# Inexperienced but still want to be a good Stack Overflow citizen?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I actively participate on several other sites that maintain a high degree of [decorum](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/decorum), post quality, and content accuracy.  I appreciate those traits, and I would like to contribute to that end here.  Unfortunately, other than some [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB), it has been a decade since I have done any programming, and then only basics in (engineering) college classes.  I see that I have much to learn.  I have already read the FAQ here, and for some things on Stack Exchange.

Topics I can speak with knowledge about:

- Shadetree automotive repair
- Design and implementation of professional sound reinforcement systems and/or equipment
- Working in a clean room
- The reaction behavior of certain ceramics with high temperature gasses

I doubt any of these are particularly relevant here!  Are there community activities other than answering questions that I can undertake while climbing the coding learning curve?  I don't want to be merely a "drive-by" poster.

Comment: I, too, am full of knowledge and skills that no one will ever ask questions about! Perhaps you and I can both talk at the same time of our various esoteric exploits while ignoring the other and talking louder and louder.

Comment: The skills in your second bullet could be useful here: http://audio.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'll go look at audio, thanks Robert

Comment: Out of random curiosity: how clean? //someone who occasionally works in moderately clean conditions.

Comment: I worked in a Class 1 cleanroom in Austin, TX, the wafer fab formerly known as AMD FAB 25, and now a flash RAM fab for Spansion.  It is just down the street from SemaTech, if you know Austin.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As long as you ask *good* (properly phrased, clear, readable, understandable) questions, there is no problem with asking *only* questions. Don't worry too much about "giving back" on that level - if you see something you can and want to answer, do it. Otherwise, nobody is going to look funny at you if you don't.

That said, there is a number of other [StackExchange](http://stackexchange.com) sites apart from programming, and a number of [upcoming sites](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), that may profit from your participation!

Comment: Pekka, thanks for the answer, I will look around area51